# Would an increase in star density affect the "Goldilocks Zone"?

Tags: science-based, astronomy, stars, habitability, galactic

Let's say that there's a solar system that matches the description of Sol exactly, save for the fact that it's **20,000 light years closer/farther to the galactic center**.

Would the zone of one astronomical unit from the sun no-longer be able to support life as we know it due to increased heat and other radiation from the higher number of stars that are now much closer to it, resulting in this solar system's habitable zone being further away from its sun, or does the star density of the area of a galaxy that a solar system is located within have no (or, at least, negligible to the point of being moot) bearing on its "Goldilocks Zone"?

Answer (score 6):

The answer in this particular case is no, because even 20,000 light-years closer to the center of the galaxy the distance between stars is fairly large.

Much of the stellar number density in the Milky Way can be described as the sum of two disks of stars, the [thin disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_disk) and the [thick disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thick_disk). The radial dependence in each of the two terms is exponential, so scaling like $e^{-R/L_i}$ with $R$ the cylindrical radial coordinate and $L_i$ the scale length. Different studies give different values for each disk (e.g. [Jurić et al. 2008](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/523619) lists $L_{\mathrm{thin}}=2.6$ kpc for the thin disk and $L_{\mathrm{thick}}=3600$ kpc for the thick disk), but let's say we can approximate both by $L_{\mathrm{thin}}\approx L_{\mathrm{thick}}\approx3$ kpc -- we're interested in orders of magnitude here.

The Sun is roughly 27,000 light-years from Galactic Center; a system 20,000 light-years closer would therefore be 7,000 light-years from the center. The stellar number density at that location relative to the stellar number density at the Sun's location is then higher by a factor
$$f=\frac{e^{-(7000\;\mathrm{lightyears})/(3\;\mathrm{kpc})}}{e^{-(27000\;\mathrm{lightyears})/(3\;\mathrm{kpc})}}=\frac{0.489}{0.0633}\approx7.7$$
This isn't really that high! And the mean distance between stars can be found from the stellar number density by $l\approx n^{-1/3}$, so this star system would have a mean inter-star distance lower by a factor of $7.7^{-1/3}\approx0.51$.

On average, stars would be half as close together as they are now -- not a huge difference! The flux from a star scales with the inverse square law as $r^{-2}$, so each star's contribution to the flux on the planet would only be higher by a factor of 4; that's still quite negligible. The habitable zone will stay the same.

It's true that a slightly higher number density would mean more close passes between stars, which could make it slightly harder for planets to remain bound to their parent stars -- but only slightly. Close interactions between stars mean the rate of passes to a given system should be proportional to the number density (see [these notes](https://w.astro.berkeley.edu/%7Eechiang/classmech/gd2_chapter8.pdf)), so the risk of the system being disrupted would increase by an order of magnitude. Still, that, too, will not be high. Environments with extremely high stellar densities -- notably, the cores of globular clusters -- can certainly [negatively affect the stability of planetary orbits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03789), but those number densities are much higher than those in either of the regions in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing or decreasing density of stars in space should have little effect on habitability of planets until the stellar density gets very large.

A star will generally be surrounded by stars in all directions and the farther the stars are the more the radiation received from them will be equal in all directions.

So only the light from nearby stars might be brighter in some directions than in others.

The Earth orbits the Sun at a distance of 1 Astronomical Unit or AU.  A light year is the distance traveled by light in one year or 63,241 AU.  In our part of the galaxy the nearest star to another star is usually about four or five light years away.

So if the nearest star to a G2V type star is four light years away and is another G2V type star, a planet orbiting the first G2V star at a distance of 1 AU will by 252,964 times closer to the first star than to the second.  The square of 252,964
is about 625 billion, so the light from the star 1 AU away will be about 625 million times as intense as the light from a star 4 light years away.

If a star's nearest neighbor is 1 light year away, a planet 1 AU from the star will receive 3,999,424,000 times as much radiation from the star 1 AU away as from the star 1 light year away.

If a star's nearest neighbor is 0.1 light year away, a planet 1 AU from the star will receive 39,994,240 times as much radiation from the star 1 AU away as from the star 0.1 light year away.

If a star's nearest neighbor is 0.01 light year away, a planet 1 AU from the star will receive 399,942.4 times as much radiation from the star 1 AU away as from the star 0.01 light year away.

If a star's nearest neighbor is 0.001 light year away, a planet 1 AU from the star will receive 3,999.424 times as much radiation from the star 1 AU away as from the star 0.001 light year away.

Of curse most stars are much less luminous than a G2V star like the Sun.

In any case the radiation from the neighboring stars will not be enough to head up a planet even slightly and thus move the habitable zone of a star even slightly father from that star.

There are some problems with various locations in the galaxy.  The farther a star forms from the galactic center, the lower will be the concentration of heaver elements in the star and the planets.  Also the earlier a star forms, the lower the concentration of heavier elements will be in the star and its planets, and a planet old enough to have highly advanced multicellular lifeforms should be billions of years old.

So stars in the outer reaches of the galaxy are much less likely to have all the heaver elements needed for planets to form or for planets to have all the trace elements necessary for at least Earth life forms.

There are also problems with the higher density of stars near the galactic center.  Stars orbit the galactic center of mass in billions of separate orbits. Thus stars are constantly getting closer to each other, passing, and then getting farther away from each other.

The less the average separation between stars is, the higher the probability will be that passing stars with pass close enough to disrupt the orbits of their planets and kill any life on those planets.

The less the average separation between stars is, the higher the probability will be that a specific planet orbiting a specific star will be have all life killed by a nearby supernova or the beam from a gamma ray burst.

And possibly some of the more mathematically skilled members here could calculate the survival odds of a planet at a specific distance from the galactic core of the Milky Way Galaxy.